# Can Android file system be written to from a class that is not an activity?

Tags: java, android, io, android-activity

I am writing an app that needs to write and read from the android file system every once in a while. The app consists of an ActionBarActivity that hosts three different fragments. My plan is to make a model class that manages all of my data and reads/writes to the android file system when it deems fit. So far I can't figure out how to make a class that is not an activity gain access to theses features.

My end goal, if possible, would be to allow I/O to work on it's own in the model class to keep coupling to as little as possible.

Here is the current code I am trying to get to run in my Model.

```
private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";
    Scanner s;

    ArrayList<Player> loadedRosterList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("applicationRoster.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                s = new Scanner(receiveString);
                s.useDelimiter(",");

                Player newP = new Player(s.next(), s.next(), s.next());
                loadedRosterList.add(newP);
            }

            inputStream.close();

            currentRoster.replacePlayers(loadedRosterList);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Android project is like any other java project. Just add a new class file and use it within the activity. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new class separate from the activity. Due to this, android will now allow me to directly access the file system. I'm trying to find a way around this to keep my model preserved.

Comment: @cmw2379 - that is not correct.  Android doesn't care what class you do the filesystem access from, only what process it runs in and who owns that.  Some of the specific file access methods rely on a Context object to figure out the appropriate directory paths, but you can either pass a Context as Szymon suggests, or figure out the proper path from the Context in your Activity class and then save/pass the actual path to classes which need to do filesystem work (you don't need to worry about leaking the path in the way you need to worry about leaking a Context object)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Context` to your method:

```
private String readFromFile(Context context) {

}
```

Be careful not to leak the context to outside of this method to avoid memory leaks.